# Submit function within form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, onclick

I am currently editing a script I had made for me some time back. I no longer have contacts for the original coder due to no longer using Yahoo messenger.

On my contact form it uses the onclick="$('#contact-form').submit()" function.

I am trying to get the contact form the submit but when I complete the form and click "Apply" it will not submit, My guess is down to the Javascript validating some of the fields that I have changed or deleted. Is there a way I can get round this? I have removed the onclick function however it will not submit when I try to complete the form.

Here is my form heading:

```
            <div id="contact-form" class="box1 form css3" xmlns:pageScript="urn:pageScript">
                <a name="loanform"></a>
                <form action="thankyou.php" method="post" id="contact-form">
                    <fieldset class="loan">
                                <legend><span>1 - Your Details</span></legend>
                                                    <ol class="group" data-role="listview">
                            <li class="clearfix" id="ValItem">
                                <label for="Val" id="ValCheck">Amount</label>
```

And for the bottom of the form as the form has a fair few fields...

```
    <fieldset class="submit" style="height:0;overflow:hidden">
                        <ol class="group" data-role="none">
                            <li></li>
                        </ol>
                    </fieldset>

                    <div id="warning-box">
                        <p>By pressing the APPLY button below you agree to our Terms and Conditions.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="full-width clearfix">
                        <div id="previousButton" class="prev-button"><img class="full-width prev-desktop" src="back-button.png" border="0"/><img class="full-width prev-mobile" src="back-button.png" border="0"/></div>
                        <div id="nextButton" class="next-button"><img class="full-width next-desktop" src="next-button.png" border="0"/><img class="full-width next-mobile" src="next-button.png" border="0"/></div>
                        <div id="SendEnquiry" name="SendEnquiry" onclick="$('#contact-form').submit()" class="apply-button"><img class="full-width apply-desktop" src="apply-button.png" border="0"/><img class="full-width apply-mobile" src="apply-button.png" border="0"/></div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <button id="popButton" style="display:none">x</button>
            </div>
```

I do not get any error messaged displayed, When you click the Apply button it does not seem to do anything. I have no objection as to how the form can be submit, I am really just looking for a way round it to make sure clients are able to submit there request.

Comment: Hi A Wolff, How can i edit this? Thanks

Comment: Done that now, Sorry Wolff

Comment: No error in console? Are you including jQuery?

Comment: As i am new to coding i dont know if jquery is being included, i know the validating script that is being called is called:  complete.js  my guess is this script is causing the form not to send as if i remove this script the form does not operate properly. i was not sure if there was a simple way round this that i could attach to the form in html that would bypass any validation taking place and execute the POST to Action without calling the script to validate on submit

Comment: Just seen this in console:   no element found d29a:1
Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead. jquery.min.js:3

Comment: This needs jQuery to be included: `onclick="$('#contact-form').submit()"` Or you could use the js way, no need to include jQuery then: `onclick="document.getElementById('contact-form').submit()"`  **EDIT following your previous comment's edit:** So you are including jQuery, not sure then why your code doesn't work. You should try to replicate your issue online so someone could check it.  PS: are you binding any `submit` handler to the FORM which could prevent its default behaviour?

Comment: Will try to run the page now without the jquery script running and change the onclick to:   onclick="document.getElementById('contact-form').submit()" as you mentioned and will see if that works, I did not create the original so i have no idea how the coder put it together to execute.. Still self leaning the basics with help from S/O :)

Comment: Tried removing the jquery.min.js script and the form will not operate right so it definitely needs that script included

Comment: In terms of your question with the binding, all i know is that the submit code is how i placed in the original question above

Comment: Even with jQuery included, could you try: `onclick="document.getElementById('contact-form').submit()"`. If still not working, consider to provide online link where your issue can be checked

Comment: Hi Wolf, tried that but no joy... am i able to provide you the link in private message, The reason for this is because the form and site is in test mode and it is a project for our main site and the code could be unsecured at this stage.

Comment: Wolff i have sent you an email to the address provided in your profile.

Answer (score 1):

As you said "I have no objection as to how the form can be submit, I am really just looking for a way round it to make sure clients are able to submit there request.", You can also sumbit as below.

Just write this line above `</form>` tag.

```
<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT"/>
```

This line will add new button in your page. You can replace it with your old button's css.

This way is very simple and you do not need to include jquery in  your html page.

Comment: Hi user3134634, i would use this command and i have tried this. The only reason this will not work is due to the form being a process form (This is all designed to run on 1 page) However the user has to fill in selected details then click Next.. Fill in more information.. Click next again then at final stage the (Next Button) switches to (Apply Button)